# VBA - Runtime error '3129'

Tags: sql, database, vba

I am trying to execute following statement in Microsoft Access using VBA:

```
Dim SQLText As String
SQLText = "INERT INTO [Tabela] VALUES (1, '1');"
DoCmd.RunSQL SQLText
```

But I get error message: **"Runtime error '3129' Ivalid SQL statement; expected DELETE, INSERT, PROCEDURE, SELECT OR UPDATE"**

**Info**: Tabela is table which has two columns: 'id' (AutoNumber) and 'a' (text)

Does enyone know what I am doing wrong?

Thanks for help! :)

Comment: INERT... Should be INSERT...

Comment: OMG! Thanks men! My mistake :)

Answer (score 3):

You misspelled "insert", you have "inert" which is a non-reactive gaseous element, not a SQL key word.